# can a relative date query can be performed on Solr

Tags: solr

I'm working with Solr data sets. I'm thinking is there a way through which I can query(date query) such that it's is relative to each record date field

To explain it further..

Each record has a `date` field all I need is a list of all records whose date has passed the 30-minute window.

Just to how to

I have a JSON structure of form and I have applied indexes on `created_at`

```
{id: 1, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:00:00Z"}
{id: 2, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:01:00Z"}
{id: 3, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:02:00Z"}
{id: 4, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:10:00Z"}
```

Let's say If I'm querying at `00:33` I would return 3 records.

```
{id: 1, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:00:00Z"}
{id: 2, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:01:00Z"}
{id: 3, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:02:00Z"}
```

and If I query at `00:41` it should return 4 records.

```
{id: 1, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:00:00Z"}
{id: 2, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:01:00Z"}
{id: 3, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:02:00Z"}
{id: 4, created_at: "2018-06-28T:00:10:00Z"}
```

To explain this further. If I have to do the same in PostgreSQL I can try this.

```
select * from [table] where now() - created_at > interval '30 minute'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr supports [using Date Math in queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html). 
To retrieve anything where `created_at` is at least 30 minutes ago, you can use:

```
created_at:[* TO NOW-30MINUTES]
```

This will return anything that was created at least 30 minutes ago. Using `NOW` means the query won't be cached (since the value of NOW changes between each request), so if this is a query that's run many times each second, you can pregenerate those values in your controller before Solr sees the values, or you can use the query parameter `NOW=<unix timestamp>` to set a common value across all request. Another option is to use NOW/MINUTE to round the value to the beginning of the current minute instead.

To get everything that's in the past (which was what your previous query example indicated, but the postgresql query didn't):

```
created_at:[* TO NOW]
```

Comment: `created_at:[NOW-30MINUTES TO NOW]` is not relative to each row created_at field,right? This could miss all record that was created before [NOW-30MINTES TO NOW]. The Point here is to compare the created time with the current time if the difference is > 30 minutes then return the result.

Comment: That's correct - since you've completely changed your examples now, that does not give you the correct answer any longer :-) I'll update my answer.